# Is there a way for a gameobject's collider to only respond to a pinch gesture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I have a collider that when grabbed (pinch gesture), it runs a method. However, I don't want the collider react to select events. Right now, the collider prevents buttons behind it being pressed. So when the pointer is coming from the hand, the ray stops at the collider and doesn't reach to the button behind it.

From my understanding, if there is a collider, the hand interaction ray stops at it, no matter what components it has. My guess is that I need to have a layer that ignores these colliders that still allows for a grab event to be registered. But when I added a layer for the Pointing Raycast Layer Mask, it correctly ignores the collider for the far interactions, but fails to recognize a grab event.

This is how my interactable component looks:[Interactable Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zssoo.png)

I appreciate any help! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the input settings, change the size of Pointing Raycast Layer Masks. Set UI to be element 0 so that pointing events react to that first. [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/version/releases/2.0.0/Documentation/Input/Pointers.html)